# European call option delta and maximum principle

Tags: delta, european-options, parabolic-pde

From [comments](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22135/european-call-option-delta-upper-bound/22209?noredirect=1#comment31627_22209), the maximum principle for parabolic PDE can be used to show that the European call option delta cannot be greater than 1. I am looking forward to such derivations.

Comment: I know I still owe you the answer. I will try to get to it. Please remind me from time to time. :-)

Comment: @Hans: No worry. I was curious.